# SP Workflow- How to start approval workflow based on multiple conditions?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, multiple-values

Here is an example of what I am trying to do. I have the following list-

List 1
**Course-----Approver_Group---Approver_Level** 
Course_1----Group_A------------Level1
Course_1----Group_B------------Level2
Course_2----Group_C------------Level1
Course_2----Group_D------------Level2

List 2
**Course-----Creator** 
Course_1----User_A
Course_2----User_B

The workflow is set for List 2. When a course is updated, the workflow first assigns task to Level1 approver group. So the lookup should assign task for approver group where 'Course from List 1= Course from List 2 and Approver_Level = Level 1'. 
I see the option of setting only one condition. How do I set multiple condition?

Comment: is it 2010 or 2013 WF?

Comment: I have access to SP 2010. If there is an easier solution in SP 2013, please feel free to let me know. I can upgrade (site is SP2013).

Comment: well, I was thinking that if you are using SP2013 workflows, you can invoke a SharePoint 2010 workflow from it. So this is a way to can call multiple workflows and each one can be configured for a certain condition